# Print custom string with character and character count without using python built-in methods

Tags: python, string

I would like to tweak my string to print the character and the character count without using python built-in methods.

```
>>> string = 'aaaabbbddd'
```

I am looking for this output:

```
a4b3d3
```

Comment: "Tweak" implies that you've done something already.

Comment: "a4b3d3" is the desired output.

Comment: Yes, we got that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with no built in methods!

```
def count_modify(string):
    d = {}
    for i in string:
        if i in d:
            d[i] += 1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return ''.join(str(x)+str(d[x]) for x in d)
```

Alternatively you could decide to not use the `join()` method and instead do the following

```
def count_modify(string):
        d = {}
        for i in string:
            if i in d:
                d[i] += 1
            else:
                d[i] = 1
        n_str = ''
        for i in d:
            n_str += str(i)+str(d[i])
        return n_str
```

Now the only obvious methods used are the `str()` methods!

Answer (score 1):

This might look like a bit long but i hope this will solve your problem

```
string='aaaabbbddd'    
elems=set(string)
result=''
for ele in elems:
    result = result+ele+str(string.count(ele))
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: nice one...but you are using count() and have also created a set data structure, which is not what i was looking for.

Comment: Oh..my bad.. as i mentioned it is not the best solution but will solve the case :)